# Запись голосовой модели для синтезатора

Tags: tts, синтезатор-речи

В личных целях хочу записать собственный голос для синтезатора речи. Есть ли синтезаторы/библиотеки, предоставляющие такую возможность? Желательно на python, но не принципиально.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/record-custom-voice-samples

Comment: Сервис, к сожалению, платный. Хотелось бы что-то опенсорсное/бесплатное.

Comment: espeak не использует голоса, а синтезирует..

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/speechpro/blog/358816/ смотри что нашёл по теме